# Easiest to balance formula for damage?

Tags: balance, combat

The problem with:

```
Damage dealt = damage - defense
```

is that you get a situation where no one will ever choose attack speed vs damage  because high attack speed players risk doing hundreds of 0 damage hits per minute and critical hits become the meta.

For now,

```
damage dealt = damage / defences
```

seems the fairest and in fact most games use this formula, but I was wondering if there are better options, especially since this only equalizes offensive stats but not defensive ones.

When damage is divided by defense, health points become mathematically useless. League of Legends deals with this problem by making all defensive stats have a hard cap with incredible diminishing returns while making health potentially infinite with no diminishing returns.

Other games ignore the problem completely.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a satisfying answer to this question, because what constitutes "balance" varies from game to game, depending on the kind of experience that game aims to deliver and the kinds of gameplay it wants players to focus on. If you're working on a specific game, it might prove more fruitful to ask "How can I adjust my damage formula to better meet the following goals..." being very specific about the problem to solve in the context of this one game.

Comment: Be aware that there are already questions about damage formulas in this site, just a search away.

Comment: If it is easier to increase the attack speed by 50% than flat dmg by 50%, players will collect attackspeed. If a player has 10.000 attack but only 1.0 attackspeed, increasing it to 1.5 might be easier farmed/ crafted than getting 15.000 attack

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where limited randomness needs to be introduced.

Add a constrained random variable to each factor in all equations.

The randomness will limit the determinism beyond fixed values.

The randomness will tilt the balance one way or the other.

Comment: Why does limited randomness need to be introduced? Why is tilting the balance one way or the other good? In what way does this make the formula "easier to balance"?

Comment: @DMGregory, using fixed formulas guarantees fixed results. The balance with my answer then becomes how much randomness is needed for each variable.

Comment: "Why is tilting the balance one way or the other good?"  It eliminates dominate strategies.  By introducing variance.